# Adding LambaExpression to an instance of IQueryable

Tags: linq, lambda

```
 ParameterExpression parameter = Expression.Parameter(typeof(Product), "x");
        MemberExpression Left = Expression.MakeMemberAccess(parameter, typeof(Product).GetProperty("Name"));
        ConstantExpression Right = Expression.Constant(value, typeof(String));
        BinaryExpression expression = Expression.Equal(Left, Right);
        LambdaExpression lambada = Expression.Lambda<Func<Product, bool>>(expression, parameter);
```

Now how do I add this lambada to an instance of an IQuerybale, lets say _query

_query.Where(lambada.Compile());?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think you just need to change the type of `lambda`

```
ParameterExpression parameter = Expression.Parameter(typeof(Product), "x");
MemberExpression Left = Expression.MakeMemberAccess(parameter, typeof(Product).GetProperty("Name"));
ConstantExpression Right = Expression.Constant(value, typeof(String));
BinaryExpression expression = Expression.Equal(Left, Right);
Expression< Func< Product, bool > > lambda = Expression.Lambda<Func<Product, bool>>(expression, parameter);
```

Now it is an `Expression<Func<Product, bool>>` and `IQueryable.Where` takes that as an argument. `Expression.Lambda<TDelegate>` returns a `TDelegate` that is also a `LambdaExpression` which is why `Expression.Lambda` line compiles in your case and in my case, but `IQueryable.Where` wants to see it as an `Expression<Func<Product, bool>>`.

Something like:

```
List< Product > products = new List< Product >
{
    new Product { Name = "bar" }, 
    new Product { Name = "foo" }
};
IQueryable< Product > queryable = products.AsQueryable().Where( lambda );
```

Answer (score 0):

Don't use `.Compile`, it would transform the expression into a delegate. An `IQueryable` is filtered using an expression, not a delegate :

```
_query = _query.Where(lambada);
```